# What is the bank sensor attached to on a Honda CBR1000RR 2012?

Tags: honda, motorcycle

I am repairing a bike which had its front totally taken out. The instruments panel and headlights are gone. One of the first things I'd like to do is install a new bank sensor. I purchased the bank sensor already, however I am not sure where I should connect it to? Does not look like the main wiring harness, looks like somewhere else. A picture for an answer would be much appreciated ; )

Comment: will it help   http://www.google.co.in/imgres?sa=X&biw=1024&bih=600&tbm=isch&tbnid=iM1C7aHN7P6GEM:&imgrefurl=http://www.apriliaforum.com/forums/showthread.php%3F244336-Bank-Angle-Sensor-Tilt-switch-location&docid=0NYGHwnAnZhDkM&imgurl=http://www.apriliaforum.com/forums/attachment.php%253Fattachmentid%253D182593%2526d%253D1328425208&w=600&h=357&ei=MsTsUaj1OMqxrAevuIGQDA&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:45,s:0,i:221&iact=rc&page=6&tbnh=173&tbnw=283&start=40&ndsp=8&tx=148&ty=47

Comment: Akash, thanks. I think it is attached to sub wiring harness.

Comment: so it helped you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shows were you should place the bank sensor:

[image]

[Image Source](http://www.apriliaforum.com/forums/attachment.php?attachmentid=182593&d=1328425208)